# Render anti-aliased text on transparent surface in pygame

Tags: python, text, fonts, transparency, pygame

I'm making a function that takes a string a breaks it up into lines and returns a surface with each line rendered below the previous one.

For example:

`Line1\nLine 2`

Renders into:

```
Line1
Line2
```

Anyway, my problem is that I cannot return a properly transparent surface to the calling function. I've tried using a color-key, but it does't work with anti-aliased text. Is there a way I can do this? Thanks for your answers.

My code: (Currently leaves an ugly purple shadow around text)

```
def render_message(messages):
    surfaces = []
    height = 0
    max_width = 0

    for message in messages.split('\n'):
        surf = FONT.render(message, True, (0, 0, 0))
        surfaces.append(surf)
        height += surf.get_height() + 5
        if surf.get_width() > max_width:
            max_width = surf.get_width()

    result = pygame.Surface((max_width, height))
    result.fill((255, 0, 255))
    result.set_colorkey((255, 0, 255))

    top = 0
    for surface in surfaces:
        result.blit(surface, (max_width/2-surface.get_width()/2, top))
        top += surface.get_height() + 5

    return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posted a second answer since this is more complex, people might want to see both.*

[image: multiline text screenshot]

- `1` , `2` decrease/increase font size
- `space` toggle BG

I left text wrapping out. Edit `parse_text()` to create a list of text you want.

```
import pygame
from pygame import Surface
from pygame.locals import *
# Todo: remove font object from TextLine() , to TextWall(). Then share a list of font's with any line.

"""Example of multi-line text class, with alpha transparency."""
lorem = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquet
tellus eros, eu faucibus dui. Phasellus eleifend, massa id ornare sodales, est urna
congue tellus, vitae varius metus nunc non enim. Mauris elementum, arcu vitae tempor euismod, justo turpis malesuada est, sed dictum nunc nulla nec mauris. Cras felis eros, elementum vitae sollicitudin in, elementum et augue. Proin eget nunc at dui congue pretium. Donec ut ipsum ut lacus mollis tristique. In pretium varius dui eu dictum.

Proin pulvinar metus nec mi semper semper. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin in diam odio. Vestibulum
at neque sed ante sodales eleifend quis id dui. Mauris sollicitudin, metus a semper consectetur,
est lectus varius erat, sit amet ultrices tortor nisi id justo. Aliquam elementum vestibulum dui ut auctor. Mauris commodo sapien vitae augue tempus sagittis. Morbi a nibh lectus, sed porta nibh. Donec et est ac dui sodales aliquet tristique et arcu. Nullam enim felis, posuere vel rutrum eu, euismod a purus. Morbi porta cursus libero, id rutrum elit lacinia vitae.

In condimentum ultrices ipsum, ut convallis odio egestas et. Cras at egestas elit. Morbi
quis neque ligula. Sed tempor, sem at fringilla rhoncus, diam quam mollis nisi, vitae semper
mi massa sit amet tellus. Vivamus congue commodo ornare. Morbi et mi non sem malesuada rutrum. Etiam est purus, interdum ut placerat sit amet, tempus eget eros. Duis eget augue quis diam facilisis blandit. Ut vulputate adipiscing eleifend. """

class TextLine(object):
    # Manages drawing and caching a single line of text
    # You can make font size, .color_fg etc be properties so they *automatically* toggle dirty bool.
    def __init__(self, font=None, size=16, text="hi world"):        
        self.font_name = font
        self.font_size = size
        self.color_fg = Color("white")
        self.color_bg = Color("gray20")

        self._aa = True 
        self._text = text                
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(font, size)
        self.screen = pygame.display.get_surface()

        self.dirty = True
        self.image = None
        self._render()

    def _render(self):
        # render for cache
        """no AA = automatic transparent. With AA you need to set the color key too"""
        self.dirty = False        
        self.image = self.font.render(self._text, self.aa, self.color_fg)            
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def draw(self):
        # Call this do draw, always prefers to use cache
        if self.dirty or (self.image is None): self._render()
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)        

    @property
    def text(self):
        return self._text

    @text.setter
    def text(self, text):
        self.dirty = True
        self._text = text

    @property
    def aa(self): return self._aa

    @aa.setter
    def aa(self, aa):
        self.dirty = True
        self._aa = aa

class TextWall(object):
    # Manages multiple lines of text / paragraphs.
    def __init__(self, font=None, size=16):
        self.font = font
        self.font_size = size        
        self.offset = Rect(20,20,1,1) # offset of whole wall

        self.screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
        self.dirty = True
        self.text_lines = []
        self._text_paragraph = "Empty\nText"
        self._render()

    def _render(self):
        # render list 
        self.dirty = False
        self.text_lines = [ TextLine(self.font, self.font_size, line) for line in self._text_paragraph ]        

        # offset whole paragraph
        self.text_lines[0].rect.top = self.offset.top

        # offset the height of each line
        prev = Rect(0,0,0,0)        
        for t in self.text_lines:
            t.rect.top += prev.bottom
            t.rect.left = self.offset.left
            prev = t.rect

    def parse_text(self, text):
        # parse raw text to something usable
        self._text_paragraph = text.split("\n")
        self._render()

    def draw(self):
        # draw with cached surfaces    
        if self.dirty: self._render()
        for text in self.text_lines: text.draw()

    @property
    def font_size(self):
        return self._font_size

    @font_size.setter
    def font_size(self, size):
        self.dirty = True
        self._font_size = size

    @property
    def text(self):
        return self._text_paragraph

    @text.setter
    def text(self, text_paragraph):
        self.dirty = True
        self.parse_text(text_paragraph)

class Game():
    done = False
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode ((640,480))
        self.text = Surface([200,100])

        self.text_wall = TextWall()
        self.toggle_bg = True

        self.text_wall.parse_text(lorem)

    def loop(self):
        while not self.done:
            self.handle_events()
            self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        if self.toggle_bg: bg = Color("gray60")
        else: bg = Color("gray20")

        self.screen.fill(bg)        
        self.text_wall.draw()        
        pygame.display.update()

    def handle_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: self.done = True

            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE: self.done = True                
                elif event.key == K_SPACE: self.toggle_bg = not self.toggle_bg
                elif event.key == K_1: self.text_wall.font_size -= 3
                elif event.key == K_2: self.text_wall.font_size += 3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = Game()
    g.loop()
```

Comment: So let me see if I understand your answer. You're basically eliminating the need for a transparent surface by just drawing each line of text directly to the screen?

Comment: No. It renders text to a new surface which has alpha transparency. ( Which is variable level, color keys only use a single level ). When you want to blit it to the screen, then you blit this surface.

Comment: Forgive me for being so dense, but where is the Surface that uses this variable transparency? All I see is fonts being blitted directly to the screen.

Comment: `self.image = self.font.render(self._text, self.aa, self.color_fg)` Creates a new image. It uses alpha variables, so each pixel will be RGBA ex: `(100,100,100,50)` meaning they have alpha values which are in the range 0-255, instead of only RGB values. It's like how `png` images have variable transparency. but if you `set_colorkey` you only get one pixel color as full transparency which is lke a `gif` image.

Comment: Right. Okay, I think I understand now. Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 2):

Got it working. Main not I found is: **no AA = automatic transparent. With AA you need to set the color key too**

Here's working example, and it toggles BG to ensure it is transparent.

```
import pygame
from pygame import Surface
#from pygame.locals import Rect, Color
from pygame.locals import *

class TextWall():
    def __init__(self, font=None, size=300):
        # for simplicity uses one font, one size for now.
        # You also can make font size, .text, etc be properties so they *automatically* toggle dirty bool.
        self.font_name = font
        self.font_size = size
        self.color_fg = Color("white")
        self.color_bg = Color("gray20")
        self.aa = True 
        self.text = "hi world"

        self.dirty = True
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(font, size)
        self.screen = pygame.display.get_surface()


    def _render(self):
        # re-render
        """no AA = automatic transparent. With AA you need to set the color key too"""
        self.dirty = False        
        self.text1 = self.font.render(self.text, self.aa, self.color_fg)            
        self.rect1 = self.text1.get_rect()

    def draw(self):
        # blits use cached surface, until text change makes it dirty
        if self.dirty or self.text1 is None: self._render()
        self.screen.blit(self.text1, self.rect1)

    def text(self, text):
        self.dirty = True
        self.text_message = text # parse

class Game():
    done = False
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode ((640,480))
        self.text = Surface([200,100])

        self.text_wall = TextWall()
        self.toggle_bg = True
    def loop(self):
        while not self.done:
            self.handle_events()
            self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        if self.toggle_bg: bg = Color("darkred")
        else: bg = Color("gray20")

        self.screen.fill(bg)        
        self.text_wall.draw()        
        pygame.display.update()

    def handle_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: self.done = True

            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE: self.done = True                
                elif event.key == K_SPACE: self.toggle_bg = not self.toggle_bg
                elif event.key == K_a: 
                    self.text_wall.aa = not self.text_wall.aa
                    self.text_wall.dirty = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = Game()
    g.loop()
```

edit: Improved code, uses alpha channel instead of set_colorkey.

Comment: I'm sorry, but on my machine the problem persists even with your code. I downloaded and ran your code, but I still see gray around the letters. I changed the font colors, background colors, and just about everything I could think of, but it refuses to be transparent.

Comment: My code with no changes does that? I just tested mine again and it worked. -- Do you have any flags on your display or a certain bits per pixel set?

Comment: Yes. I ran your code verbatim, and there was gray around the edges. Not very much, (probably because the system font is very linear) but still there. Setting the background and color-key to green makes it more visible. I don't know about the flags, as far as I know everything is set up to the defaults.

Comment: It has to alias to something. I chose gray as my bg, so when you switch the screen to red, there is a little gray around the text. So choose the forgeround and background colors to what you expect.

Comment: But my background is an image with complex patterns. I want to render text to that. Is that not possible?

Comment: I got alpha working without a color. Remove the set colorkey, and use this `self.text1 = self.font.render(self.text, True, self.color_fg)` -- No background color argument uses the alpha channel.

Comment: Well...yeah. I got that far, but I want to blit a bunch of fonts onto a transparent surface, then blit that onto another surface. The middle step is what's tripping me up. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to not use a color key, but rather an alpha channel.  Instead of this:

```
result = pygame.Surface((max_width, height))
result.fill((255, 0, 255))
result.set_colorkey((255, 0, 255))
```

Try using this:

```
result = pygame.Surface((max_width, height), pygame.SRCALPHA)
```