# Efficiently handle text in PyGame

Tags: text, pygame, blit

After encountering a number of problems with the rendering of text in PyGame, I wonder, if there are any efficient ways to deal with it.

**First approach:**

store the texts already rendered in a classes self.variables:

```
class SomeClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.text1 = myfont.render("Text 1",0,self.colour)
        self.text2 = myfont.render("Text 2",0,self.colour)
        #etc.
```

then in the event handling, I just blit the variable:

```
while running:
screen.blit(SomeClass().text1,(x, y))
```

*Note: myfont is a pygame.font.SysFont(...)*

Result: Framerate dropped from >29 (limit is 30) to roughly 20 to 22.

**Second approach:**

store just the text strings in a classes variables and render before blitting.

```
class SomeClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.text1 = "Text 1 string"
        self.text2 = "Text 2 string"
```

and then render just before the blitting:

```
while running:
    #more code
    screen.blit(SomeClass().myfont.render(SomeClass().text1,0,SomeClass().colour)
```

Result: Comparable drop of Framerate

**Third approach:**

using GIMP, writing the text there and then store it in PNG.
Result: No noticable change in FPS

So the question remains: Is there any way to efficiently handle text in PyGame or is it always the better solution to make it pictures? Did I just not understand a basic rule of text handling in PyGame? Did I overlook something?

How do you handle texts in your Py-Games?

Thanks in advance for all opinions and suggestions ;)

Patric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cache the text render. Try this demo: [Render anti-aliased text on transparent surface in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488293/render-anti-aliased-text-on-transparent-surface-in-pygame/15516132#15516132)

It will only re-render if dirty. ( changing `.text` or `.aa` ) by using properties.

Edit: You maybe be interested in the newer GUI module http://program.sambull.org/sgc/ for more.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very interesting approach. I will give it a shot.

Comment: Wondering something else now... Doesn't the "print" command consume a lot of CPU too...? After I removed the command to print the FPS the game suddenly worked notably faster.