# 2 functions in pygame related code not working. (probably syntax)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I wrote a code to make a game where, a player moves upwards and downwards, and has to dodge the flames. But the waitforkey() and drawtext() functions are not working at all.
so the code gives an error as soon as the game ends.

here is the code :

```
    #Import modules

    import pygame, random, sys
    from pygame.locals import *


    #intialising variables for ease

    window_height=600 
    window_width=600
    blue = (0,0,255)
    black = (0,0,0)

    fps=30
    flamesize=20
    speed = 5
    addnewflamerate =20

    #defining the required function

    def terminate():        #to end the program
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    def waitforkey():       #to wait for user to start
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == "QUIT":
                    terminate()
                if event.type == "KEYDOWN":     #to terminate if the user presses the escape key
                    if event.key == "K_ESCAPE":
                        terminate()
                    return



    def flamehitsmario(playerrect, flames):      #to check if flame has hit mario or not
        for f in flames:
            if playerrect.colliderect(f['rect']):
                return True
            return False

    def drawtext(text, WindowSurface, font, x, y):        #to display text on the screen
        textobj = font.render(text, 1, blue)
        textrect = textobj.get_rect()
        textrect.topleft = (x,y)
        WindowSurface.blit(textobj, textrect)


    #end of functions, begin to start the main code

    pygame.init()
    mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
    WindowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width,window_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('MARIO')

    #setting up font and sounds and images

    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

    playerimage = pygame.image.load('player.png')
    playerrect = playerimage.get_rect()
    flameimage = pygame.image.load('flame.png')

    #getting to the start screen

    #waitforkey() : if i remove the '#', the game hangs.

    drawtext("Mario", WindowSurface, font, (window_width/3), (window_height/3))
    drawtext("Press any key to start", WindowSurface, font, (window_width/3-50), (window_height/3+50))

    pygame.display.update()
    #start for the main code

    topscore = 0
    while True:

        score = 0
        flames = []
        playerrect.topleft = (50,window_height/2)
        moveup = movedown = False
        flameaddcounter = 0

        while True:     #the main game loop
            score+=1
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    terminate()

                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_UP:
                        movedown = False
                        moveup = True
                    if event.key == K_DOWN:
                        movedown = True
                        moveup = False

                if event.type == KEYUP:
                    if event.key == K_UP:
                        moveup = False
                    if event.key == K_DOWN:
                        movedown = False
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        terminate()

            flameaddcounter += 1


            if flameaddcounter == addnewflamerate:

                flameaddcounter = 0

                newflame = {'rect' : pygame.Rect(window_width - flamesize,random.randint(0, window_height - flamesize), flamesize, flamesize),
                            'speed' : speed,
                            'Surface' : pygame.transform.scale(flameimage, (flamesize,flamesize))
                            }
                flames.append(newflame)

            if (moveup and (playerrect.top > 0)):
                playerrect.top -= speed
            if (movedown and (playerrect.bottom < window_height)):
                playerrect.bottom += speed

            for f in flames:
                f['rect'].left -= speed

            for f in flames:
                if f['rect'].left <= 0:
                    flames.remove(f)

            WindowSurface.fill(black)
            WindowSurface.blit(playerimage, playerrect)

            for f in flames:
                WindowSurface.blit(f['Surface'], f['rect'])

            pygame.display.update()

            if flamehitsmario(playerrect, flames):
                if score > topscore:
                    topscore = score
                drawtext('GAME OVER', font, WindowSurface, (window_width / 3), (window_height / 3))
                drawtext('Press a key to play again.', font, WindowSurface, (window_width / 3) - 80, (window_height / 3) + 50)
                pygame.display.update()
                waitforkey()

            mainClock.tick(fps)
```

And the required images :

http://inventwithpython.com/player.png 
http://haryanacitygas.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/flame.png

THANKS :D.

Comment: It's a lot of code to look through, but it looks like after 'GAME OVER', you want to wait for the user to press a key?  The problem with your `waitforkey` function is that it is only ever going to call `pygame.event.get` once, so if there are no events queued at the time that `waitforkey` is called, it's not going to do anything.  If this sounds like your problem, let me know and I'll format an actual answer with code.

Comment: Yes, when I call the function waitforkey before the game loop, it does not do anything. The text is displayed and key press is not detected.

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: For text, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488293/render-anti-aliased-text-on-transparent-surface-in-pygame/15516132#15516132

Answer (score 0):

```
if event.type == "QUIT":
```

You are seeing if `event.type` is equal to the string "QUIT".  It will not be.  Nor will any of the other events be equal to strings.

pygame defines a number of constants (`int`s actually) that you should test against.

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    #etc
```

And similarly for your other `event.type` checks.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you switch the order of the arguments you pass to the function 
`drawtext`. In your game loop you call the function with these arguments

```
drawtext('GAME OVER', font, WindowSurface, (window_width / 3), (window_height / 3))
```

But you define the function like this:

```
def drawtext(text, WindowSurface, font, x, y):
```

As you can see the font argument is passed in the place of the WindowSurface argument, and hence you are trying to basically render from a surface instead of a font :).
Just fix the order with which you pass the arguments to the function and it should work smoothly :)